# Error: Cannot find module 'commander' in stencil on Local server

Tags: bigcommerce, stencils

I have installed stencil on local server. I am getting this error when I run the`stencil init` command:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'commander'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\payal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\bin\stencil:3:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That error is typically indicative of a Node version problem.  Try switching to Node 4.4.5 and reinstalling Stencil.  I use [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to manage multiple versions of Node on my machine, works like a charm.